# String to int/float, plenty of multiple columns - R

Tags: r, loops, types, readr

I have a df with +100 columns and their datatypes are:

```
> table(sapply(df,class))

character    factor   integer 
      107         1         8
```

However, there are plenty of `chr` columns which actually are integers or floats. The next columns `(a,b,c)` are an example from those `chr` datatype columns in my df:

```
          a         b           c    
1        "4"     "35.2"       "4"    
2        "6"     "21.4"       "6"    
3 "No value"    "-10.1"  "No value"    
4        "4"     "25.4"       "3.2"    
5        "2" "No value"       "6.5"    
6        "5"     "65.0"  "No value"
```

I know how to select each column and replace the `"No value"` for `NaN` and then changing the columns from `chr` to `integer` or `float`. The problem is, they are near 60-70 columns. So, it's a very time-demanding task and I think there should be a more efficient way. I have been trying these alternatives:

1. A loop through the columns df with an if statement (still trying to figure out what kind of if statement could assure me no hidden errors as I can't check if the 60-70 columns are converted accordingly).
2. Trying to figure out a way in reading code (read.csv(), read_table(), read.delim(), etc.) to give as output the df with the right data types and replacing the `"No value"` with `NaN` automatically.

So, do you know a more efficient way to transform those 60-70 `chr` columns (with numeric values) to integer/float/numeric datatypes, than transforming them one by one?

Comment: Can't you do `read.csv("path/to/data.csv", na.strings = "No value")` ? This should solve both of you problems.

Comment: I think `"No value"` would be replaced with `NA`, not `NaN`, fyi. I'm not convinced there is a huge functional difference, but there is a logical difference between them: `NaN` says there is no number defined, as in `0/0`, while `NA` suggests a missing (or un-interpretable) value. One good article on this: http://onetipperday.sterding.com/2012/08/difference-between-na-and-nan-in-r.html